# Proving an infinite product formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, products

I have found this formula and I am trying to prove it , but I have not any idea how to deal with it:

$$e^{ax}-e^{bx} = x(a-b)\exp\left[\frac{a+b}{2}x\right]\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\left[1+\frac{(a-b)^2x^2}{2k^2\pi^{2}}\right] $$

It's too complicated for me, any suggestions ?

Answer (score 9):

We have the following [infinite product representation for $\sinh\,z$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/4.36.E1):

$$\frac{\sinh\,z}{z}=\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{z^2}{k^2\pi^2}\right)$$

Comparing this with

$$e^{ax}-e^{bx} = x(a-b)\exp\left[\frac{a+b}{2}x\right]\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\left[1+\frac{(a-b)^2x^2}{2k^2\pi^{2}}\right]$$

we find that

$$\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\left[1+\frac{(a-b)^2x^2}{2k^2\pi^{2}}\right]=\frac{\sinh\frac{x(a-b)}{\sqrt 2}}{\frac{x(a-b)}{\sqrt 2}}$$

Use that $\sinh\,z=\frac{\exp\,z-\exp(-z)}{2}$ to prove/disprove your equation.

Comment: it's clear , thanks for your help .

Comment: Prigmin, there's a check mark next to Yuval's answer or mine that you can click if you're happy with any of them.

Comment: Yes,I've already do that . Thanks .

Answer (score 3):

This is the famous sine product formula in disguise. See for example [this writeup](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-104-seminar-in-analysis-applications-to-number-theory-fall-2006/projects/chan.pdf).

Comment: A good answer.  Unless, of course, the next step is the USE this formula to prove the sine product formula...